# The action x could not be found for yController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and am encountering an error in Chapter 10, where I add the ability for users to edit their information. Submitting the form in the edit page gives the following error:

```
Unknown action: The action 'update' could not be found for UsersController
```

I have read through about 10 identical questions on StackOverflow, so I apologise for the duplicate, but in each of those cases the problem was that they had prematurely ended the `UsersController` class, or had not defined the appropriate action. I have quite explicity defined the `update` action inside `UsersController`, and have quadruple-checked the number of `end`s being used. Here is my `users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Account successfully created! An email has been sent to
                                             #{@user.email} for validation."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I've also double-checked all my routes to make sure it's correct:

```
$ rake routes
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         statics#home
   signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
    login GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#new
          POST   /login(.:format)          sessions#create
   logout DELETE /logout(.:format)         sessions#destroy
    users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

And this confirms that my `users#update` is properly routed. I can't for the life of me figure out why the `update` action is not being picked up. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**
As requested, here is the server log for the request:

```
Started PATCH "/users/1" for ***** at 2016-07-12 04:43:43 +0000

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'update' could not be found for UsersController):
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  <lots of irrelevant internal rails stuff>
Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/unknown_action.html.erb within rescues/layout (2.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you check your request passing as "PATCH" or not in server logs?

Comment: It is indeed passing as patch:
`Started PATCH "/users/1" for ****** at 2016-07-12 04:43:43 +0000`

Comment: Could you add more from the logs when this happens?

Comment: even though you get the error, can you check if your user is indeed updated?

Comment: The user is not updated. I'll edit the question with the part of the server logs relating to the request.

Comment: `  <lots of irrelevant internal rails stuff>` can you actually include the very first line of this... it's not so irrelevant if it shows which LOC is throwing the error :)

Comment: I've added the first three lines.

Comment: AbstractController -> Are you inheriting your controller from AbstractController? In logger it seems that.

Comment: The users_controller.rb file shows that UsersController inherits from ApplicationController. I don't know what goes on internally with Rails.

Comment: Check all routes -> If any route is overlapping with  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format) , confirm that. as it goes firstly in AbstractController.

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping routes? All the routes in the app are shown in the original question; none of them seem to be 'overlapping'.

Comment: All routes routes of application displayed here ? I can't find where you used abstract controller. And Overlaping routes means -  PATCH  /users/:id occurs multiple time in routes file.

Comment: In that case, I can say no, there are no overlapping routes. All routes are shown in the question. AbstractController appears to be a class used internally by Rails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117040/discussion-between-shefalee-chaudhary-and-nemo).

Comment: Is that definitely the right file? Could rails be picking up a UsersController defined elsewhere ?

Comment: An interesting suggestion, but this is the only users_controller.rb file in the application, and the only place where a UsersController is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back the next day and reopening my workspace on Cloud 9 revealed that the `users_controller.rb` file had not saved correctly. This was most likely caused by a temporary disconnection. The `edit` and `update` actions were not in the saved file, and re-adding them resulted in the application working correctly.

For anyone else having the same problem, if you are using Cloud 9 or another online workspace, I suggest checking your internet connection and/or closing and reopening your workspace.